# RMarkdown HTML output - poor resolution in different browsers?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm rendering an RMarkdown document with ggplots to HTML.  Unfortunately I'm unable to post a replicable example, but here's the gist of the problem:

The plot looks nice and crisp in the RMarkdown document.  It also looks crisp in the default output (when I knit the RMarkdown, an HTML document opens up within R).

When I open the same HTML document in chrome, it looks notably lower-resolution.

Here it is within R, nice and crisp:

[image]

Here it is within chrome (blurry):

[image]

Same exact HTML document.  What gives?

Comment: what happens if you use a different graphics device (html uses png by default) such as `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'svg')`

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to try a solution if you can't replicate the issue? I think this may be solved if you tried

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
    mode: selfcontained
---
```

Which creates a self contained HTML file by base64 encoding images, which I hope would retain the higher quality image.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I tried this, and it's still much clearer within the R HTML output than it is in chrome..

Comment: I suspect it's directly cause by fig.height and fig.width - I've had to change these beyond the default due to my plot sizes.  But still can't figure out why it looks great within R, and crappy in chrome.

Comment: You may try setting explicitly the `{knitr}` [plot options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) at the top of the document (under the YAML). Example: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.retina = 1, out.width = "100%")`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend switching to .svg instead of .png

This has some advantages and disadvantages but, for me at least, solves the problem with playing with dimensions of the rendered graphic. Chrome and Edge / Internet Explorer seems to have no problems whatsoever with displaying .svg in htmls I generate from R Markdown and share with collaborators.

Please see here for how to change format:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/graphical-device.html

This new package in Tidyverse might be of use too:
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/svglite-2-0-0/

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your zoom. Make sure to set the zoom to exactly 100% for both browsers. I had this issue before.

Comment: Do you mean the zoom in chrome - setting it in Chrome ?  If so, I don't think that's the issue..

Comment: hmm did you try using another browser.  Now I'm curious what is the engine rendering rstudio is?